# Samba gvfs mount and symbolic link seems not to work

Tags: mount, samba, fuse, gvfs

I have a server with samba shares and 2 HDs mounted that I use for backup. I have some symbolic links that work well between these 2 hard drives.
When I mount the drives with gvfs (samba) I can't use the symbolic link.

`ls` from the client:

```
 $ls -al
 drwx------ 1  users 0  4 mag 17.09 .
 drwx------ 1 feboss users 0 13 dic 00.13 ..
 drwx------ 1 feboss users 0 15 nov 00.14 FILM
 drwx------ 1 feboss users 0 18 apr 22.49 foto
 ?????????? ? ?      ?     ?            ? torrent
 ?????????? ? ?      ?     ?            ? TV
```

`ls` from the server:

```
$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup 4096 mag  4 17:09 .
drwxrwxrwx 9 feboss feboss  4096 dic 13 00:13 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 feboss feboss    14 nov  7  2013 FILM -> /mnt/3TB/FILM/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 feboss feboss    17 mag  4 17:09 foto -> /mnt/3TB/100D5100
lrwxrwxrwx 1 feboss feboss    25 nov 11  2013 torrent -> /mnt/2TB/TORRENT/complete
lrwxrwxrwx 1 feboss feboss    11 nov  7  2013 TV -> /mnt/2TB/TV
```

Can someone explain how I can fix this? Obviously, I can't make new symbolic link from the client.
If I mount with cifs everything works well but it is not automatic like gvfs.